# Do EA-6B Electronic Countermeasure Officers focus on one task at a time?

Tags: military, us-navy, electric-aircraft

I was wondering do the 3 Electronic Countermeasure Officers on the EA-6B all focus on doing the same task at once? Or does each of the ECO have a specific task assigned to them on the mission that they just focus on (Tactical jamming, Navigation, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prowler ECMOs rotate seats, and while sitting in the front right seat they function as a copilot.  There is no second set of controls as some aircraft have, but they are responsible for operation of the navigational and communication equipment.

In the back seat their primary responsibility is to operate the tactical mission equipment.  This includes radar signal receiving, analyzing and jamming.

Actual sharing of these duties between the two backseaters was largely dependent on workload, crew experience, and personal preference.  There really weren’t any hard and fast rules other than to work as a team to maximize effectiveness.  The mission commander for each flight had a responsibility to get the job done, but otherwise had leeway in the leadership style and method used for assigning tasks.